# HASHBYTES() function usage in Sql server2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, md5, hashbytes

i came to know that Sql server2008 introduce HASHBYTES() which use md5 to encrypt any string like this way `Select HASHBYTES( 'md5', 'demo' )` and the the code used to decrypt like this way

```
Select CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), HASHBYTES( 'md5', 'demo' ), 2)
```

but when i try this second select statement it is showing the value in encrypted format. so how to decrypt the demo as text. thanks

Comment: Generally the `MD5` algorithm is not symmetric.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's one way hashing; you can't get back original form. It is not possible to decrypt a hash. 
What is the purpose though?

if you are just trying to compare this hash value with some other then you can do something like

```
IF HASHBYTES('md5', 'demo') = HASHBYTES('md5',@param) 
    PRINT 'Match!';
```

**EDIT:**

Hashing does not encrypt the original value at all.  Hashing instead applies a one-way mathematical algorithm to the original value, resulting in a binary value.

It's mainly used for storing password. so, the password will be stored in hash format. When user provides credential (id/password); it doesn't decrypt the stored password; rather, user provided password will be hashed with the same algorithm and that hash value will be compared with the stored hash value (as shown a code example above).

Comment: @Thomas, short answer "NO". It's a hash value and not encryption. How will you decrypt.

Comment: @Thomas, see edited answer for an explanation. Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: can u tell me if i want to encrypt and decrypt data in sql server then how i can do that.

Comment: @Thomas, see here http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/28/sql-server-introduction-to-sql-server-encryption-and-symmetric-key-encryption-tutorial-with-script/